# How to organize an array in a table view into alphabetical sections

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making an app with a table view and I want to be able to sort through the table data like the native Contacts app where the first letter of a name is sorted with all the other names that have that same first letter. I'm using a mutable array.

Here is the code for the Table in the implementation file (This is not all the code from the file, just the portions of it that are for the table):

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.doctorNames = [NSMutableArray.alloc
                        initWithObjects:@"Aaron Smith", @"Michael Jordan", @"Cormac Chester", @"Marcus Baloutine", @"Joe Schmo", @"Sly James", @"Barack Obama", @"Joe Biden", @"Superman", @"Batman", @"Robin", @"Commissioner Gorden", @"Joseph Gordon Levitt" ,nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [self.doctorNames count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [UITableViewCell.alloc
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [doctorNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    return cell;
}

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate*resultPredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    searchResults =[doctorNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString*)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
    scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
    objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure isn't setup correctly. You want an array of section data. Each element of the array should be a dictionary. Each dictionary should have a key for the section title and a key for an array of rows in that section.

Having one big array isn't appropriate for a sectioned table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to sort your array in alphabetical order:

```
[self.doctorNames sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: This doesn't provide enough information to display multiple sections in the table view.